# OpenVPN: Can I access a VPN client from a system in the network

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I want to use a shared resource in my office network to connect to a developer's laptop which is connected to the office network via openvpn. The VPN connection works fine and it assigns 10.8.0.10 as the ip for the laptop. When I ping to 10.8.0.10 from the VPN server, it works fine; but I am unable to ping to this IP from any other devices in the office network.

How can I solve this; what I should do? Or is it fundamentally wrong?

Comment: This is a bit confusing can you clean it up. I'm guessing you are outside the office and connecting to the office via OpenVPN. The developers laptop is inside the office? or is the developer laptop the one you are using to connect to the office?

Comment: @mhaselup - Sorry for the confusion. I am the developer connecting to the office network. There is a shared computer in the office from which I want to access the web site in my computer.

Comment: If you are connected to the office via VPN what can you access at the moment?

Comment: I can access all devices in the office network. But non of those devices can access (ping to) my device except the VPN server.